# Problemas ao manipular Vector Asset

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

O Android Studio tá retornando esse erro quando adiciono imagens ao meu projeto, mas as imagens selecionadas são os ícones nativos da IDE.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar esse valor como default no seu build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig{
   vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

e coloca também o appcompact nas dependências:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Comment: `<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageAll"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_all_unselected"
            android:tint="@color/menuItemUnselected"/>`

Consegui resolver dessa forma. Será q posteriormente ele dá erro novamente dessa forma que fiz? Essa é uma boa prática?

Comment: Da forma que você fez está correto. Você está definindo o xml no drawable e depois colocando como source em um imageview e definindo a cor. Não tem problema nenhum nisso e provavelmente vai funcionar tranquilamente! ;)

Comment: Obrigada pela ajuda :D

Answer (score 0):

​Consegui resolver meu problema desse jeito. Primeiro eu coloco a imagem pra poder setar a cor dela. Espero que não dê mais problema :D

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]